# About iframes. Need to display a website portfolio that demonstrates responsive design

Tags: javascript, iframe, seo

It's often said that iframes are bad for SEO (this worries the client) and should be avoided in most cases (from the research I've done). I would like to avoid them but I can't find an adequate alternative, to summarize, I have a website portfolio that needs to be displayed on the home url (example.com) and showcases the use of responsive design. A JavaScript solution is offered here at, also a demo is linked via github:

Source: https://github.com/OriginalEXE/Switcheroo

This is great, seems to do exactly what i need. I've checked the developers material for a mention of SEO, but found nothing. Now I've read some conflicting material on how Google treats iframes, for instance what if I kept the iframe content on a sub-domain such as (portfolio.example.com - showing a basic html homepage of a clients site) is Google known to treat sub-domains differently? (Again I've tried to find info about this). The content in the iframe doesn't need to be crawled, only the parent url. (example.com)

I've read that some people might use PHP to display the content like this (display a 3rd party site, framed and the ability to resize between mobile/tablet/desktop) however a previous developer was already building a WordPress plugin which was causing all kinds of security holes. I'd prefer to keep any solution on the front end/JavaScript.

Finally I've read about the use of robots.txt, would this stop Google trying to crawl the iframe content, can't find any clear answers. I'm happy to elaborate more on this, and apologies if my question isn't clear, I've been sitting on this problem for some time and I've been unable to find any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed google crawls iframe.

As long as the pages [invoked in the iframe] are designed in SEO friendly manner, then you do not need to worry about google not crawling to it.

Alternatively, if you have created a subdomain, you may submit the link to Google Webmaster so that it is crawled.

As of today, Yahoo and Bing have problems crawling iframe content.

Please read the following resources to confirm the hypothesis...

[Post 1](http://www.audiencebloom.com/2014/01/google-known-crawl-iframes-website/)

and this

[Post 2](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have read and it has helped. You see I don't actually need (and perhaps want to avoid) the iframe content to be crawled, I guess I could submit the sub-domain pages to be crawled separately and not via the iframe.

 I found a [link](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60140/does-meta-name-robots-content-nofollow-prevent-indexing-iframes) which suggests that using JS to generate the href links for the iframe, will hide them from search engines therefore I assume leaving the SEO score intact. Now the Switcheroo method I mentioned above generates the links in JS.

Comment: ...to follow on from above. So because JS generates the links the iframe will be ignored (I hope). At least that's my interpretation of it all ! Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid my reputation is too low! It says I need 15 points or more to do that. Sorry, however I'll mark it when I get some more.